# Even though I use % 1000000007 it still results on 0

Tags: c

my goal on this code is to make exponential operations without pow().
It works for evey value a^b which b <= 30. I'm aware that I should be using  x % 1000000007 to prevent integers overflows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {
        int i, a, b, rst;
        rst = 1;
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++){
            rst = rst * a;
            if( b == 0){
                rst = 1;
            }           
        }
        printf("%d\n", rst % 1000000007);
        return 0;
    }
```

Why does it returns a "0" for example on "2^40 % 1000000007" even though I'm using % 1000000007?

Comment: What is the logic behind your `% 1000000007`? Where did that particular number come from? If `int` is 32 bits on your system, then it can't hold a vale of 2**40. Try adding a `printf` call or using a debugger to track the value of `rst` through and after the loop.

Comment: A quick Google search indicates that `% 1000000007` is common in programming contests: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-1097-1000000007/

Comment: The problem is that after 32 times through the loop, the value in `rst` is 0. That's because 2^32 mod 2^32 = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you don't need if statement in for loop.
**Second**, you are trying to stop integer overflow after it already happens. So you need to do it after every multiplication operation.
**Third**, you can use `unsigned long long int` instead of `int`, because `int` is machine dependent (may be 1000000007 is too big for int on your machine).

I guess this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int i, a, b, rst;

    scanf("%llu %llu", &a, &b);

    rst = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++){
        rst = (rst * a) % 1000000007;
    }
    printf("%llu\n", rst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not `1000000007` that's too big for `int` (it's less than 32 bits). It's `rst`.

Comment: @KeithThompson But sir, I think `rst` is not going to be bigger than `1000000007`. Or Am I missing something?

Comment: The loop computes `a**b` (a raised to the b'th power). The example the OP used was 2**40. Your modified version avoids overflow by applying `% 1000000007` at each step.

Comment: @KeithThompson, So you are saying that my code prints wrong answer (which is 511620083)?

Comment: I wasn't talking about your code. I'm saying that in the OP's code, it's not `1000000007 ` that's too big for `int`, it's `rst` when `a` and `b` are `2` and `40`, respectively.